# In XAML two stackpanels overlay in a grid

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have this XAML on my windows phone:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding LocalizedResources.balance, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
            <StackPanel Margin="15,0,0,0" >
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="AccountsInfo" Grid.Column="1">
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
                            <local:RateChart x:Name="rateChart" Height="324" Margin="-12,25,0,0" Width="417" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

In AccountsInfo Stackpanel I have like 5 accounts added programatically and RateChart is a chart. However, my rate chart should be below all the accounts and at the moment it is right in top of the screen and overlays first accounts. I don't know how to do the orientation.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like all you need is something like this. We get rid of the unnecessary panels, actually specify to your second `StackPanel` where it needs to be positioned within the parent `Grid` while ditching some unnecessary values on other properties. Hope this helps.

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding LocalizedResources.balance, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">            
   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <StackPanel x:Name="AccountsInfo">
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <local:RateChart x:Name="rateChart" 
                             Width="417"
                             Margin="0,25,0,0" />
         </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```